# Wordpress display shortcode icon in html view

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have put off visual editor in wordpress and i cannot access the button that allows me to insert shortcodes.What should i do to view the insert short code button?

Comment: Shortcode button? Where's that then? If you're referring to a button added by a plugin, please provide the name and link to it so people know what it is you're talking about..

Comment: Its a gallery plugin.I found it though.I edited media.php in wp-admin/includes.I thought there was a general way of doing it via a plugin,looks like am gonna have to write that myself.

Comment: I'll need more information to go on than that. Shortcodes should work in both modes, so without knowing the code involved it's impossible to diagnost your issue. If you want to write your own shortcode there's a whole page devoted to explaining how, here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/). after you install it, go to your dashboard and set the button layout the way you want it to be... (you will be able to put your gallery plugin button where you want it to be)